# Бэби-театр или бэби театр?

Tags: орфография

Склоняюсь к бэби театр, типа детский театр, для малышей. Верно ли я рассуждаю?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете *отдельное* слово в позиции и со значением *прилагательного*, то у него должно быть соответствующее окончание. Поскольку невозможно образовать такое прилагательное ("бебический"?), остается присоединить используемое слово (грамматически это существительное) через дефис, с образованием слова *беби-театр* (ср.: "*беби-бум*" из Русского орфографического словаря 2012 года).

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем правильно переводить «a baby theatre» как «бэби-театр». В английском языке относительные прилагательные образуются расположением существительного перед другим существительным, а в русском языке заменой или добавлением морфем в конце слова. Вы же не переводите «a iron bridge» как «железо-мост». Насколько я понимаю, «a baby theatre» это не театр для детей, а театр для очень детей. Правильным переводом будет «театр для малышей». Но такое слово(бэби-театр) уже присутствует и закрепилось в языке. Возможно, люди использовали это слово по неким стилистическим мотивам — иностранное слово в названии заведения. Тут не остается другого варианта, кроме как писать это слово через дефис.